# how do I bridge a function taking a closure as a parameter to objc

Tags: objective-c, swift, language-interoperability

I have

```
func verifyEmail(let email: String, let completionHandler:(Bool) -> Void) -> Bool
{
```

in my (swift) framework

exposing it as

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT BOOL verifyEmail(NSString *email, void (^completionHandler)(BOOL verificationResult));
```

in my framework umbrella header

attempting to call it like so

```
verifyEmail(@"dfs", ^(BOOL verificationResult) {
    NSLog(@"objc: using sdk v%f", whateverSdkVersionNumber);
});
```

in objective c sample code results in a link error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_verifyEmail", referenced from:
      -[ObjCExample verify] in ObjCExample.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Same with other functions exported but if I can map closures
to blocks or whatever I'll surely fix the rest :^)

Resolved: converted globals to class func()s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access Swift functions declared in global scope in your Objective-C code. Per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75):

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s marked with the `@objc` attribute as long as it’s compatible with Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - **Top-level functions defined in Swift**
> - Global variables defined in Swift
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types

Including  `FOUNDATION_EXPORT ...` in your umbrella header exposes only the function's definition, the symbol itself is not ported to Objective-C.

Comment: Indeed, I just added a superfluous @objc class and added a class func which promptly got exported in the generated swift->objc bridging header. Thanks!

Comment: untyped or even explicitly Int typed swift enums don't seem to be exported (Anton breaks the table)